# How to Read Cassandra Performance Tracing Table

Tags: cassandra

In Cassandra 3.5 I set the "TRACING ON" and run a select and got the following table. I am not sure how to read it. Can you tell me the second subtask "parsing statement" took 139 microsecond or 192-139 =53 microsecond? The guide on datastax website is not very clear.

Sorry if the format is too messy, please refer to my link.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHbpm.png

```
activity    timestamp   source  source_elapsed
Execute CQL3 query  2016-05-11 12:33:21.124000  192.160.75.0    0
Parsing SELECT * FROM ratesbt.metrics where name = 'A' ; [SharedPool-Worker-1]  2016-05-11 12:33:21.124000  192.160.75.0    139
Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-1]   2016-05-11 12:33:21.124000  192.160.75.0    192
Executing single-partition query on metrics [SharedPool-Worker-2]   2016-05-11 12:33:21.124000  192.160.75.0    348
Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-2]  2016-05-11 12:33:21.124000  192.160.75.0    366
Key cache hit for sstable 142 [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2016-05-11 12:33:21.124000  192.160.75.0    397
Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2016-05-11 12:33:21.124001  192.160.75.0    409
Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-2]    2016-05-11 12:33:21.124001  192.160.75.0    421
Read 3972 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-2]  2016-05-11 12:33:21.135000  192.160.75.0    10962
Request complete    2016-05-11 12:33:21.141442  192.160.75.0    17442
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its time elapsed from the timestamp that the request started. So depending on the message (most events are after an action occurs, but some can mark before they start) you can figure out whats taking most time.

In your case its the reading of the 3k cells off of disk and merging it with the memtable which took 11 milliseconds. That isn't bad if the sstable[s] were not being cached by OS (depending on disks).

Comment: Thank you Chris. But what is the time spent after the 11ms? It says when entire process took 17ms to complete. Does cassandra merge memtable and sstable first or read ssttable first? I am confused by the process.